# Do body armors have any effect on the head? Is it better to use hollow point ammunition when targetting a body-armored enemy's unarmored head?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm just wondering if Fallout New Vegas is like Skyrim, where wearing an armor on one body part will protect other body parts (regardless if armor is worn on that body part).

In FNV, do body armors have any effect on the head?  Will it be better to use [hollow point ammunition](http://www.falloutwiki.com/Fallout:_New_Vegas_ammunition) (does more damage to unarmored opponents) on an enemy *with* body armor, but *no* helmet or head armor or other head apparel when targetting the head?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a long time, but if I remember correctly, the armor you have is armor overall, but the Head gets a reduced amount from the armor based on a percentage, and headshots have a multiplier, I believe 2x damage.

So the Armor does help your head, but with a diminished effect. As for Hollowpoint rounds, I think that so long as you can see skin/flesh you're fine.

Comment: "*So the Armor does help your head, but with a diminished effect.*" Do you mean "body armor does protect the head, regardless if one is wearing head armor or other head apparel"?

Comment: Yes, but I think that it's less for the head. Like if you have a total of 100 armor I think the head only applies about 50 of it.

Comment: To add to this: From [this Bethesda - FNV forum thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1362262-do-body-armors-have-any-effect-on-the-head/page__view__findpost__p__20550755): "*Armour does affect the entire body, including the head. Someone wearing Leather Armour will have 6 DT everywhere, but a headshot does double the damage*" "*...helmets as far as I know only add on additional DT bonus. You don't have hit location division of your DT*".